# Setting batch number for set of records in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have following data in csv

```
id,date,records
1,2019-03-28 01:22:12,5
2,2019-03-29 01:23:23,5
3,2019-03-30 01:28:54,5
4,2019-03-28 01:12:21,2
5,2019-03-12 01:08:11,1
6,2019-03-28 01:01:21,12
7,2019-03-12 01:02:11,1
```

What i am trying to achieve is set a batch number that should keep on increasing after moving sum value crosses 15 and the moving sum should reset as well, so i am trying to create batch for records that has total moving sum value as 15

For ex. if Moving sum becomes 15 the batch number value should increment, which would given me rows containing total value of 15.

so the output i am looking for is if the cumulative sum exceeds 15 -

```
id,date,records, moving_sum,batch_number
1,2019-03-28 01:22:12,5,5,1
2,2019-03-29 01:23:23,5,10,1
3,2019-03-30 01:28:54,5,15,1
4,2019-03-28 01:12:21,2,2,2
5,2019-03-12 01:08:11,1,1,2
6,2019-03-28 01:01:21,2,12,2
7,2019-03-12 01:02:11,1,1,3
```

I am using pandas for this but not able to reset the moving_sum and carry forward the previous set batch_number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this using `df.iterrows()`.

```
moving = []
batch = []
cntr = 1
for idx,row in df.iterrows():
  if len(moving) == 0:
    moving.append(row['records'])
    batch.append(cntr)
  elif moving[-1] < 15:
    moving.append(row['records']+moving[-1])
    batch.append(cntr)
  elif moving[-1] >= 15:
    moving.append(row['records'])
    cntr += 1
    batch.append(cntr)

df['moving_sum'] =  moving
df['batch_number'] = batch
```

```
id  records moving_sum  batch_number
0   1   5   5   1
1   2   5   10  1
2   3   5   15  1
3   4   2   2   2
4   5   1   3   2
5   6   12  15  2
6   7   1   1   3
```

Comment: same problem, if I want to assign batch_number 1 to 5 to the entire row of csv file and condition is moving_sum is near about equal in all batches. What should be the best approach ?